# Puma. Is it possible to get current running requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, ruby-grape, puma-dev

We need to see current active requests in puma web server. Not in a queue. Is it possible? Could it be possible to develop it manually?
Example:
puma config: 1 worker / 1 thread

```
get /test1
get /active_requests # returns /test1

get /test2
test2 is placed to puma queue
get /active_requests # returns /test1

test1 returns 200
test2 is active
get /active_requests # returns /test2
```